# "Last domain does not have enough data columns" when combining Candlestick and Line chart for Google Charts

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

I am trying to render both a CandleStick chart with a Line chart.

Here is the JSFiddle of my failing example: https://jsfiddle.net/7wyp6yy3/1/

Here is the JSFiddle of my CandleStick chart: https://jsfiddle.net/7jadqnsb/

What I did, on top of my Candlestick code, I added the default seriesType of `candlesticks`, and assigned the 5-th column as a line-chart

```
        seriesType: 'candlesticks',
        series: {4: {type: 'line'}}
```

For my data, I simply added a fourth column of integers:

```
        ["Mon, Aug 10 2015",2080.98,2080.98,2104.18,2105.35, 500],
        ["Tue, Aug 11 2015",2076.49,2102.66,2084.07,2102.66, 500],
        ["Wed, Aug 12 2015",2052.09,2081.10,2086.05,2089.06, 500],
        ["Thu, Aug 13 2015",2078.26,2086.19,2083.39,2092.93, 500],
        ["Fri, Aug 14 2015",2080.61,2083.15,2091.54,2092.45, 500],
        ["Mon, Aug 17 2015",2079.30,2089.70,2102.44,2102.87, 500],
        ["Tue, Aug 18 2015",2094.14,2101.99,2096.92,2103.47, 500],
        ["Wed, Aug 19 2015",2070.53,2095.69,2079.61,2096.17, 500],
        ["Thu, Aug 20 2015",2035.73,2076.61,2035.73,2076.61, 500],
        ["Fri, Aug 21 2015",1970.89,2034.08,1970.89,2034.08, 500],
        ["Mon, Aug 24 2015",1867.01,1965.15,1893.21,1965.15, 500],
        ["Tue, Aug 25 2015",1867.08,1898.08,1867.61,1948.04, 500],
        ["Wed, Aug 26 2015",1872.75,1872.75,1940.51,1943.09, 500],
        ["Thu, Aug 27 2015",1942.77,1942.77,1987.66,1989.60, 500],
```

That said, I am getting the following error with my new code:

```
Last domain does not have enough data columns (missing 3)
```

I tried changing the series index to a variety of values, but no dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set `series.1` , the number doesn't refer to a column, it's the index of a serie.

What happens: default `serieType` is `candlesticks`, so the first serie (index: `0` ) will automatically be of type "candlesticks"...a candlestick-chart requires 4 data-columns

When you set `series.4` the API will automatically create `series.0`, `series.1`, `series.2` and `series.3` ....and all of them will be `candlesticks`

Let's see the data-columns as a stack of data.

The API creates the series:

1. **`serie.0`**
   ...will be `candlesticks` , requires 4 data-columns, the first 4 data-columns will be removed from the stack
2. **`serie.1`**
   ...also `candlesticks`, requires 4 data-columns, but there is only 1 data-column left on the stack (**3 are missing**....that's what the error means)

Comment: Could you please try this on the Fiddle?

Comment: Can this also do more than one line of data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: So right now we added one more line to the candlestick. Could I add another set/column of line chart data on top of the existing?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old, but I just ran into the same problem. Dr.Molle's answer put me in the right direction, but I think it could use a bit more clarification.

In summary your last column should be put at the beginning so that it looks like:

```
["Mon, Aug 10 2015",500,2080.98,2080.98,2104.18,2105.35],
["Tue, Aug 11 2015",500,2076.49,2102.66,2084.07,2102.66],
["Wed, Aug 12 2015",500,2052.09,2081.10,2086.05,2089.06],
...
```

Then in your 'options' variable you can put:

```
seriesType: 'candlesticks',
series: {0: {type: 'line'}}
```

Hope this helps other in the future!

Answer (score 0):

as a kind of an answer to theGreenCabbage's question on the accepted answer:

> So right now we added one more line to the candlestick. Could I add another set/column of line chart data on top of the existing?

```
            function drawChart(data) {
            if (data == null) return;
            var formattedData = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var rowItem = [data[i].date, data[i].low, data[i].open, data[i].close, data[i].high, data[i].line1, data[i].line2, data[i].line3];
                formattedData.push(rowItem);
            }
            var dt = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(formattedData, true);

            var options = {
                legend: 'none',
                candlestick: {
                    fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#a52714' }, // red
                    risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#0f9d58' }   // green
                },
                chartArea: { left: 40, top: 20, width: '100%', height: '75%' },
                seriesType: 'candlesticks',
                series: { 1: { type: 'line' },
                          2: { type: 'line' },
                          3: { type: 'line' } },
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(dt, options);
            }
```

well, the main parts of this function in the context of the question are:

```
var rowItem = [data[i].date, data[i].low, data[i].open, data[i].close, data[i].high, data[i].line1, data[i].line2, data[i].line3];
```

and

```
                    series: { 1: { type: 'line' },
                          2: { type: 'line' },
                          3: { type: 'line' } },
```

all the other parts are simply for those who want to take in the CTRL+C / CTRL+V way

Answer (score 0):

[Dr.Molle]'s answer is right

You have 6 columns in array - first 5 for candlestick `series.0` and the last 6th column for line `series.1`.

So, you should change this in your example to the following:

```js
// From this
{4: {type: 'line'}}

// To this
{1: {type: 'line'}}
```

Also I have added the below code on the first line:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

And I've got a working example of your chart on JSFiddle

`Saved new version`[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/ahc8xedL/